# change bullet colors while uncovering one by one (beamer)

Tags: beamer, color, itemize

How is it possible to change the bullet colors while uncovering, in this example it works when everything is uncovered but apparently not when using uncovering. 
If someone can explain the underlying logic of this behaviour it will be also interesting.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Singapore}
}

\newcommand{\gooditem}[1]{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=blue}\item #1} 
\newcommand{\pooritem}[1]{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=red}\item #1} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{I-measure}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \pooritem {\color{red}a}
        \gooditem {\color{blue}b}
        \pooritem {\color{red}c}
        \gooditem {\color{blue}d}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. I hope to have understand your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Singapore}
}

\newcommand*\pooritem{%
  \item[\color{green}\scalebox{0.9}{\textbullet}]}
\newcommand*\gooditem{%
  \item[\color{red}\scalebox{0.9}{\textbullet}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{I-measure}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \pooritem {\color{red}a}
        \gooditem {\color{blue}b}
        \pooritem {\color{red}c}
        \gooditem {\color{blue}d}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The functional difference between the static case without overlays, where your solution works perfectly fine and the uncovering is, that if you add `[<+->]` to your itemization the "normal" item is substituted by an overlay aware version of `\item`, which seems to have its own way to handle colours.

As a workaround you could simply use the features of this overlay aware item and do something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Singapore}
}

\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{parent=structure}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{I-measure}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item<+-|alert@+-> a
        \item              b
        \item<+-|alert@+-> c
        \item              d
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks much better (note that this solution requires using <+(1)->, so it will begin with only red lines). Is there also a way to open them line by line (red ones uncovering and not only blue ones) as done without alerts?

Comment: @user2964927 Please see my edited code.